# Steam FileUploader Post Request: Missing SteamID

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm trying to write a script that automates uploading a profile picture to steam. I'm writing it as single-use for now to make sure it works. I'm trying to use python requests to accomplish this.

No matter what I try, I ALWAYS get `#Error_BadOrMissingSteamID` as the response to my post request.

The url is https://steamcommunity.com/actions/FileUploader?type=player_avatar_image&sId=YourId&bgColor=262627, where YourId is replaced with your SteamID64, which I have. I know this url works, because I can view it on my browser and the response to my request is always 200.

The webpage is extremely simple, it's got a Choose File... button, a textbox to display the file name, and an Upload button. This is the important part of the source:

```
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1048576" />
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="player_avatar_image" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sId" value="MyId" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sessionid" value="SessionId" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="doSub" value="1" />
    <input type="file" name="avatar" size="16" />
   <input id="submitBTN" input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
```

where I replaced the actual session/steam IDs with MyId and SessionId.

I've been trying many things, but this is basically what I've got:

```
import requests

url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/actions/FileUploader'
picture = open("test.png", "rb")

r = requests.post(url=url,data={"type":"player_avatar_image","sId":"MyId"},files={"avatar":picture},headers={"sessionId":"SessionId"})
print(r.text)
```

I've tried using Multipart Encoding, playing around with the data/header params, but I keep getting the same error.

How can I successfully pass in my SteamID? I know the param name is "sId" because that's what's used in the url and html. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Cookies. You're not passing in the cookies that tell Steam that you're logged in! How can Steam allow a random unauthenticated person to upload an avatar for somebody else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the `steamLogin`, `steamLoginSecure` and `sessionid` cookies to Steam at a minimum so that it can authenticate you. Add those cookies to your `request` and you should be fine.

Here is code that works for me:

```
import requests

url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/actions/FileUploader'
i = '76561198246664798' # enter ID64
cookies = {
    'steamLogin': '',
    'steamLoginSecure': '',
    'sessionid': '',
}
data = {
    "MAX_FILE_SIZE": "1048576",
    "type": "player_avatar_image",
    "sId": "",
    "sessionid": "",
    "doSub": "1",

}
picture = open('pic.png', 'rb')
r = requests.post(url=url, params={'type': 'player_avatar_image', 'sId':i}, files={'avatar': picture}, data=data, cookies=cookies)
```

Fill in the required values and you're done.

Comment: Thank you! I added those, and now `print(r.text)` returns the html of the webpage. However, I can't get the image to change. I'm using `r = requests.post(url=url,params={'type':'player_avatar_image','sId':'MyId'},data={'avatar':picture},cookies=cookies)`, where cookies are the values you told me to add. I've tried changing files to data. Any ideas as to why it's not uploading?

Comment: @LucasAnderson Hold on. Let me test it:)

Comment: @LucasAnderson try using `files` for `avatar` instead of `data`. You may also need to pass `bg` parameter but try that later.

Comment: If a `bg` param isn't passed, the webpage is just black, which is fine. I've tried using `files` instead of `data` but it still doesn't work. I tried changing the image to a jpg instead of a png but that didn't work either.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to figure this out! With further testing, I've found that all you need are the `doSub` and `sessionid` properties in `data`. It makes sense that `doSub` would need to be set (can't believe I overlooked that), and I guess the `sessionid` is needed again on submission. Thanks again, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I’m not entirely sure what you need, (it will definitely be a lot of tinkering, but whenever using requests, using cURL is very beneficial. You can access processes in your web networking tab and copy them as cURL. Here is a [cURL to Python-Requests Resource](https://curl.trillworks.com) so that you can convert your cURL code into python-requests syntax. It will retain all of your login headers and cookies so that you don’t have to go through all of the tediousness of copying them and making sure that you have the right ones.

Comment: Thank you for this! It makes it a lot easier to make sense of how the request works.

Comment: @LucasAnderson No problem!